# NCHW input matrix to Dm conversion logic for convolution in cuDNN

Tags: conv-neural-network, linear-algebra, convolution, cudnn

I have been trying to understand the convolution lowering operation shown in the [cuDNN paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1410.0759.pdf). I was able to understand most of it by reading through and mapping various parameters to the image below. However, I am unable to understand how the original input data (NCHW) was converted into the Dm matrix shown in red.

The ordering of the elements of the Dm matrix does not make sense. Can someone please explain this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each column of `Dm` corresponds to a tile of the original image. Two examples are shown below:

[image: upper-left tile]
[image: upper-right tile]

There is no simple mathematical description of how to extract these tiles (authors call it "non-trivial") but some general comments in section 3.1.

A couple of notes:

1. The exact layout of data in `Dm` and `Fm` is flexible: you could permute the rows of `Dm` and the columns of `Fm` or vice-versa.
2. cuDNN does not actually construct `Dm` in full, rather it lazily generates columns of `Dm` as they are needed (see section 3.1 of the paper)
3. **Convolution or cross-correlation?** The classical definition of a convolution requires that the filters are flipped (along both axes) before applying them to the image. Modern machine-learning frameworks tend not to do this, and mathematical pedants call this a **cross-correlation** rather than a convolution. From a machine-learning perspective, it doesn't matter which one you use, but filter-flipping gives convolution nice algebraic properties (e.g. commutativity) and matches the definition of convolution used in mathematics (side note: convolve means to fold or roll). In this cuDNN paper the filters **are flipped**.

Comment: Thank you! am still having some trouble understanding why the elements of the Dm matrix are arranged in some order that is unexplained. Assume, K =1, C = 1, with this we would have the following products: 

Column 1: F0 * D4, F1 * D3, F2 * D1, F3 * D0 
Column 2: F0 * D5, F1 * D4, F2 * D2, F3 * D1 
Column 3: F0 * D7, F1 * D6, F2 * D4, F3 * D3 
Column 4: F0 * D8, F1 * D7, F2 * D5, F3 * D4 

But in the above list of products (Fm x Dm), there is no F0 * D0 which is the first product one would expect.

Comment: There are two competing conventions for image convolutions. In one, the filter is flipped (along each axis) before applying it to the image, and in the other it is left as it is. Mathematical pedants will call the [former a convolution and the latter a cross-correlation](https://glassboxmedicine.com/2019/07/26/convolution-vs-cross-correlation/). In machine learning, it doesn't matter which you use as long as you don't mix them up, and the latter is now more common. The first convention is the one being used in the paper, so no there is no F0 * D0.